# ContentPublication Limit exceeded in Unit Test

Tags: apex, unit-test, governorlimits, content, contentversion

I have Apex triggers on ContentDocument and ContentDocumentLink Sobject.

I wrote my Apex Unit Tests for those triggers and I was creating more then one Content Data record to test the Logic in Bulk.

After several Unit test running I got the error:
`System.UnexpectedException: ContentPublication Limit exceeded.`

I have encounter the System limit "maximum number of versions that can be published in a 24-hour".

It looks like system sees those test Content as real and is counting the number against the limit.
I thought that those kind of limits where not counted in the Unit Tests.

Is this a bug? Is there any one having a solution at that issue?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: are you doing this within a test.starttest() - test.stopTest() block?

Comment: Are you performing multiple `insert` operations against `ContentVersion`?

Comment: I am performing one insert of a list of ContentVersion with more then one row within Test.startTest() and Test.stopTest().

Comment: Hi @MarcoDev, did you get any further with this?  I am facing same issue.  Surprised that test records created within startTest() and stopTest() are counted against limit.